# Model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[CA1API.Models.Weather]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im creating a getting a Location type of application

I am receiving this error

```
Model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[CA1API.Models.Weather]', but this requires model item type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable [CA1API.Models.Location]'.
```

I have created my ViewModel that looks like this
namespace CA1API.Models

```
{
    public enum County
    {
        Ireland,
        England,
        Iceland
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public County LocationName { get; set; }
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lon { get; set; }
        public int WeatherID { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> Weathers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

my controller looks like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private WeatherDb db = new WeatherDb();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Weathers.ToList());
        }
    }
```

my view looks like this

```
@model IEnumerable<CA1API.Models.Location>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">County</div>
            <div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-x:hidden; height:300px;">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <p>modelItem=>item.County</p>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the top of the View Index? the line that starts with `@model ... `?

Comment: You view has `@model IEnumerable<Location>` - but your passing `IEnumerable<Weather>`. Change the view to `@model IEnumerable<Weather>` (Not exactly sure what the view should be showing, but the types must match)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Index` **View** use the `@model IEnumerable<CA1API.Models.Location>` as a **Model** and you try to pass an `@model List<CA1API.Models.Weather>` to the **View**.

Because the model you try to pass don't **inherit** or it's not the model that's expecting to be received it's throwing an exception.

> Model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List[CA1API.Models.Weather]', but this
>   requires model item type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   [CA1API.Models.Location]'.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. You're passing a `List<Weather>` where the view expects `IEnumerable<Location>`.

You probably meant `return View(db.Locations.ToList());` instead of `db.Weathers`.